# Accept different text case

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans

how do I make my search be able to accept any text case

```
private void Update_Table(){
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/IECEP","faculty","1234");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Students");
        Table_Students.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch(SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err);
    }
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter 
        = new TableRowSorter<>((DefaultTableModel) Table_Students.getModel());
        Table_Students.setRowSorter(sorter);
}

private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(((DefaultTableModel) Table_Students.getModel())); 
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(txtSearch.getText()));

        Table_Students.setRowSorter(sorter);
}
```

As of now, it only accept what is exacltly in the database. Like if the first name is "John" and last name is "Doe", you should type uppercase J for John to appear and same for last name.

Answer (score 0):

First you can always upper case the field from the table you are searching for: [Upper function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx)

Second if you are looking for partial match you can use the % for wild cards: [Sql % wild card](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

So for per your requirement you can look for uppercase words in the table while using the Upper sql function

Answer (score 0):

When you use "select * from students where lastname like 'doe'"  it will return all combinations of doe in upper and lowercases. The magic word is 'like' instead of '='. You can also use wildcards to mask your query as pointed out above.